# Track changes to code base/project in a db and have visual graph showing all work

Tags: git

I am using git for version control. During development I run a grunt watch task that livereloads the documents I work on. In git bash I can then see logs like this.

```
File "header.php" changed.
Completed in 0.000s at Thu Apr 27 2017 02:57:02 GMT+0200 (W. Europe Daylight Time) - Waiting...
```

I am looking for a way to store the data in these logs in a database. I am not looking for a way to store the actual change made to the file or to track commits. I want to be able to track time, date and hours worked either per individual file or per project folder as a whole to then be able to have a visual representation of this data in a chart showing total time worked per file and per project. Something similar to the contributions graph on GitHub, just locally and more detailed.

Is there a tool for this that can hook into git or the grunt watch task and store these logs in a database for later visual representation? For code editor I use Atom, is there perhaps a package that can accomplish this? Is there perhaps software that can do this?

The closest I have found is the blame view on GitHhub https://help.github.com/articles/tracing-changes-in-a-file/ though I want this locally and just track file, time and date changed. Did not want to ask this on SuperUser as this is coding related, thank you for any ideas or help on how I would be able to achieve this.

Comment: I don't think this is really related to git.

You could probably use grunt to store when a file is changed and the time at which it was changed and then write something to interpret that data and build a graph.

Comment: Does a script or tool like that exist already? _and then write something to interpret that data and build a graph_ sound like something to do to practice JS, would know if this can be done with pure JS?

Comment: Not that I am aware of, it seems to be quite niche. You could probably use NodeJS.

Comment: Ok, thank you and **last question**, how do devs track time worked purely on files and code, open to anything, looking for something that I can hand to clients and say "_these are the pure hours worked on code besides all other work done_".  Also to have something for myself to see were most time goes when coding. Sure there is something, no? How do other people/devs do it? Any idea?